# Slide a View over (on top) of Another view

Tags: android

I have two views, say View A and View B. Currently, view B is active. On pressing a button, view A must partly slide in ON TOP of view B, from the side.

How can this be accomplished? I have gone through the HorizontalScrollView implementation of the facebook slide in menu, but that's just scrolling through two views placed side by side. That implementation is entirely different.

Thanks,

Sid

Comment: you can simply use animation to give the sliding effect